# Rexex add <a href="tel: > </a> around all phone numbers in multiple .html pages

Tags: html, regex

I have a lot of `.html` pages which contain phone numbers of this style:

> html code: "phone: 1234-567-89123"

Now I want them all to be recognized as phone numbers if the `.html` page is rendered by a smartphone browser.
Of course, the phone number is always different, except the state code 1234, this stays always the same. The length of the phone number with state code is always 12 numbers plus two hyphens.

I need a regex which converts the following:

```
"phone: 1234-567-89123" -> 
"phone: <a href="tel:123456789123">1234-567-89123</a>"
```

To do the replace I use [this script](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/), where the interface looks like this:
[image: Interface]

So far I figgured out how to select my pattern:

```
1234-567-\d\d\d\d\d

now I need to replace that pattern with 
<a href="tel:1234567xxxxx">1234-567-xxxxx</a>
```

So I need to know how to copy the five digits into the replaced string.

The tool I am working with handles everything like I do static replacing with notepad++.

Comment: Do your want use `Javascript` or include `jQuery` library?

Comment: Are you talking about automatically doing that as part of parsing code that runs each time? (In which case, which server-side technology are you using?)  Or are you talking about static HTML that need changing?  (In which case, which editor are you using?).  Or - as prompted by @Siyavash - are you trying to do this on the client?  Either way, you've shown no evidence of trying to figure it out yourself

Comment: Hey I changed the Question and added what I tried so far and which technology I am using

Answer (score 1):

According to their GitHub, the tool uses:

> String to search for or `preg_replace()` style
>       regular expression.

If you find this:

```
"phone:\s*(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)"\s*->
```

You can replace it with this:

```
<a href="tel:$1$2$3">$1-$2-$3</a>
```

Note that `$1` refers to the first capture group, and so on.